# Looping through Entries based on MultiSelect Field Selection

Tags: forloop

I’ve got a `people` entry type that has a `peopleCategory` multiselect field. I’m wanting to loop through all the people and grab the ones that have a a specific item selected in the multiselect field (in this case - that they have been marked as being in 'leadership'). I was using

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section(‘People’).peopleCategory(‘leadership’) %}
    {% if entry.peopleCategory.contains('leadership') %}
```

but in conjunction with another if statement

```
{% if loop.index==1 %}
{% elseif loop.index==2 %} 
{% elseif loop.index==3 %} 
etc
```

and that ended up throwing off the formatting in the template  - so now I’m tyring to find a new solution using something like:

```
{% set leadershipTeamTest = allPeople.peopleCategory('leadership').peopleCategory('leadership') %}
```

or

```
{% set allPeople = craft.entries.section('People') %}
{% set leadershipTeam = allPeople.peopleCategory('leadership').peopleCategory.contains('leadership') %}
```

but having trouble where it’s either returning everyone, or no one.

I'm still a pretty new to Craft - but would appreciate any help ( was using this - https://craftcms.com/docs/multi-select-fields but couldnt get it going)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straight forward in the end =]

```
{% set allPeople = craft.entries.section('People') %}     
{% for entry in allPeople if entry.peopleCategory.contains('leadership') %}
```